# SSL added. Now W3 Total Cache redirects pages to the cache _index.html_gzip file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, caching, w3-total-cache

I have a WordPress website with the W3 Total Cache plugin.

I added SSL to my site and added a redirect in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]]
```

But whenever I test a redirect, for example, http://www.rankhigherseo.com.au/about-us/ it redirects to https://rankhigherseo.com.au/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/rankhigherseo.com.au//about-us//_index.html_gzip

I played with the settings and it now redirects to https://rankhigherseo.com.au/about-us/ but the page is still loading the one that is displayed on https://rankhigherseo.com.au/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/rankhigherseo.com.au//about-us//_index.html_gzip.

I cant find any solution to this problem.

What exactly do I need to do when I add SSL to the site to have w3 total cache still work normally?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Rob for giving some direction to find a solution.

You can find the check box for Cache SSL (https) requests under Page Cache - among a zillion other W3 Total Cache settings.

Once you're done, be sure the clear your cache, otherwise the fix may not take immediately for your site visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by going into the w3 total cache settings and checking 'Cache SSL (https) requests'